# Trying to modify an ANT task to track the PID of its JUnit execution

Tags: ant, junit

I've got an ANT macro written that runs my JUnit tests, what I would like to do is get hold of the PID (linux) for the JUnit task so that I could run jstat on it while its running and track historical performance of some key tests.

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up running a shell script in parallel to the junit task. This waits for a process that matches the two grepped conditions, runs jstat on it and then exits when complete.

```
#!/bin/bash
while :; do
   junitPID=$(ps -Af | grep java | grep ant-junit.jar | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2)

   if [[ -n $junitPID ]]; then
      jstat -gcutil -t $junitPID 1000
      exit 0
   fi
   sleep 1
done
```

There are many issues with this implementation such as not handling more than one execution per node, but that is fine as its not a situation that I need to cater for now.

Any other suggestions are welcome.